# Mapbox only with geometry features

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, data-driven

I can not `querySourceFeatures` to get only elements of non-empty geometry properties.

Example geojson:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id": 2,
    },
    "geometry": null,
}
```

If I call querySourceFeatures with filter:

```
querySourceFeatures('source', {
filter: ['has', 'geometry']
})
```

it returns nothing because all filters are applied only to the properties section of the feature.

How to achieve the result of getting only results with no empty 
geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure null geometry features are discarded. You'll need to keep track of them yourself.